# In Vaadin 8, how to convert Boolean to checkbox in a grid

Tags: java-8, vaadin8

In Vaadin 8 framework, using [Vaadin Grid](https://vaadin.com/grid), how do I present a `Boolean` object in each row as a checkbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest solution is to use the `ComponentRenderer` introduced with Vaadin 8.1 (currently beta, so you need to get it from snapshot repository). See Vaadin docs: https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-grid.html#components.grid.renderer.

Comment: You are welcome. If it helped, you can mark it as answer. For future questions please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask first if you don't want to get down-votes of your question.

Comment: components are quite heavy. you can use a simple HtmlRenderer instead.

Answer (score 3):

## Display a Unicode character

An alternative to the other correct Answer is: **plain text**. Display one of the [Unicode characters representing checkboxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checkbox#Unicode) on either state, checked or unchecked.

Write code that chooses one or the other for the Boolean value. Write the code as a [column renderer](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-grid.html), specifically a `TextRenderer`.

Answer (score 1):

**Example with VaadinIcons**

[image]

```
grid.addColumn(user -> user.isFreeUser() ? VaadinIcons.CHECK.getHtml() : null)
        .setRenderer(new HtmlRenderer())
        .setCaption("Free User");
```